# Multiple Checkbox filter not working properly in ajax...!

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

**This is my First JSP Page
I want to create a Multiple checkbox Filter page using Ajax my problem is that when i checked more than one checkbox it can replace previous checkbox value  i attached 3 files in this...so please give me solution for this problem Thankyou very much.**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Filter
    Created on : Jan 14, 2018, 3:16:01 PM
    Author     : Lenovo
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Filter</title>

        <style>
            header
            {
                background-color: lightblue;
                height: 100px;
            }

            li
            {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            #remove
            {
                display: none;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <header>

        </header>   
    </div>    
    </div>

        <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="padding:20px;">
        <h4>BRAND</h4>    
        <ul>
        <%
        String bname=null;    

        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY b_name");
        int a=1;
        while(rs.next())
        {
        bname=rs.getString("b_name");
        %>

        <li><input class="brand" id="brand<%=a++%>" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="<%=bname%>" /><%=bname%></li>

        <%
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         out.println(e);   
        }
        %>


        </ul>

        <hr>


        <h4>RAM</h4>    
        <ul>
        <%
        String ram=null;    

        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ram ORDER BY ram");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        ram=rs.getString("ram");
        %>

        <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="<%=ram%>" /><%=ram%></li>

        <%
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         out.println(e);   
        }
        %>

        </ul>


        <hr>


        <h4>PRICE</h4>    
        <ul>

        <li><input id="price" type="range" min="3000" max="100000" step="1000" value="3000" /></li>
        <div id="showPrice">

        </div>
        </ul>


        </div>   
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-9" id="load">
        <span id="remove">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: white; color: black;">Clear filter <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>    
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <div id="filter">

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>    
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FilterJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my Jquery & Ajax page**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.brand').on('change',function()
    {

       if($(this).is(":checked"))
       {
         var brand=$(this).val();


         $.ajax({
            url:"FilterAjaxDB1.jsp",
            method:"post",
            data:{brand:brand},
            success:function(data)
            {

             $('#filter').html(data);

             $('#remove').css({"border-radius":"40px"}).show().fadeIn('fast');
             $('#remove').click(function ()
             {
              $('.brand').prop("checked",false);   
             });
            }
         });
       }

       else
       {
        $('#filter').html("Not");
        $('#remove').hide().fadeOut('fast');
       }

    });
    });
```

**This is my AjaxDB file**

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : FilterAjaxDB1
    Created on : Jan 14, 2018, 5:09:48 PM
    Author     : Lenovo
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="thumbnail">

        <%

       String bname=request.getParameter("brand");

        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE b_name='"+bname+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        String name=rs.getString("m_name");
        String ram=rs.getString("ram");
        int p=rs.getInt("price");

        out.print(name+"<br>");
        out.print(ram+"<br>");
        out.print(p+"<br>");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.print(e);
        }
         %>   

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well you only use that one checkbox value so you need to look for all the checkbox values.  Depending on how you want to send it to the server determines the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a Multiple checkbox Filter page using Ajax my problem is that when i checked more than one checkbox it can replace previous checkbox value

there is something you should know,in the Multiple checkbox,if you choose more than one,you will only get one value by checkbox.value.

If you want to get all the values,you have to use for loop to check all the checkbox if the one you are checking are checked or not